# How to protect user edit paypal button ?

Tags: php, paypal

How to protect user edit paypal button ?

this is paypal buy now button on my site

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Teddy Bear">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

my customer will edit paypal button like `currency_code`, `amount`

i want to know , how can i protect user to edit paypal button ?

Comment: Use the Paypal Instant Payment Notification System(IPN). You can then verify that the currency, amount etc are all correct.

Comment: can i submit paypal form using other way like curl that's user not see paypal element ?

Comment: Submitting the form using cURL would mean the server is sending the request to PayPal not the client.

Comment: for example codecanyon.net when i purchase , i not see paypal form, and then it's will redirect to paypal.com , how codecanyon.net do ?

Answer (score 1):

Log into your PayPal account and use the button tool to create a saved button. the saved button replaces all of the sensitive data in the button code with a "Hosted button ID. here is an example of the hosted button code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="L7NSNLBNU69AC">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```